# How can I vertically align text within a span element, or make the span the same size as the text?

Tags: html, css

This seems like a pretty basic question, but I can't find the answer anywhere.  In the image below, the word "Schedule" is in a span within a span.  The blue box is not part of the CSS, it's the Firebug highlight rectangle showing the dimensions of the outer span.

[image]

Here's the HTML:

```
<span class="caption">
  <span class="green">Schedule</span>
</span>
```

I also made a [jsFiddle illustrating the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/9yu6Y/).

There is no padding or margin on either span, just some sizing and color information.  The font size is 48px, but the span height is computed to be 65px, and the text is vertically centered in this span, causing the top of the text not to line up with the clock icon, which is in a separate HTML element.

The question is: why is the span taller than the text it contains, and how can I either (1) make them the same size, or (2) align the text at the top of the span.  I want to emphasize that I am **not** setting the span height this way; Firefox is doing this, and there are no padding or margins involved.

Comment: Please provide a demo that illustrates the issue. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) is quite preferable.

Comment: Good idea!  See updated question for jsFiddle link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controlling most of the dimensions for `inline` elements will have no effect and is generally not supported (it would be directly against the intent of being inline).  You must modify the `display` to be either `inline-block` or `block`.

Comment: I understand what you mean about inline, but the issue isn't that I'm trying to undermine the layout, it's that the element is just plain bigger than it's supposed to be, so the layout looks wrong.  Why does the browser put padding on the element like that?

Comment: It's primarily governed by line-height but only loosely.  If you really want all of the details: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#q15.  The bottom line is that if you want fine control over the space occupied with an originally inline element, use inline-block.

Comment: Well, I'm still not sure I fully understand what's going on, since w3.org is not the lightest reading, but you gave me the critical suggestion.  I set display:inline-block on that outer span and set line-height:35px.  I don't really get why the line-height needs to be set to this magic number to make it work, but it did make it look right.  Thanks!

Comment: I thought I'd updated the link to be more specific.  The particular dense piece of concern is: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-non-replaced

Answer (score 0):

You'are looking for the `line-height` property. This determines the height of the text + bottom top. Also, please consider using the image as background-image like: `url('<img_url>') no-repeat left center`? This centers the image as well and you separate layout (as this image is pure for style)

So: the span needs a line-height of 48px to get the right height.

Comment: I tried this and it shifted the whole span up a little, but not enough to line up, and the computed height of the span is still 65px.  The image is just there to illustrate my layout problem, but has nothing to do with the span/text issue, as it's in a totally separate element.

Answer (score 0):

Make a div that is your container for the schedule word.

```
.container
{
display: table;
height: 200px;
width: 100px;
}

.scheduleThingaMaJig
{
display: table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

The schedule thing should be vertically centered and horizontal centering is just text-align: center on .container. You should use

instead of  I think. Also if you are just aiming to align with the img, you can but a dimension on the img and force alignment that way, disregarding your extra top/bottom whitespace on schedule.